# imagemagic convert .png to .gif high quality

Tags: imagemagick

I have an animation from Blender rendered as 500 .png images, I want to convert these 500 images into a single looping .gif file, the images are 1080x1080. How do I convert them while keeping a high quality image?

Answer (score 4):

```
convert -size 1080x1080 -delay 2 -loop 0 *.png output.gif
```

Without the -size flag I was getting artifacts for some reason trying to `convert *.png output.gif` this works,

Comment: For newer version like `ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16` on windows, the command is `magick -size 1080x1080 -delay 0 -loop 0 *.png output.gif`.